# How to dismiss a viewcontroller within another ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Let say I have view controllers named **A**,**B**,**C**,**D**,**E** I open these`ViewConrollers`one after the other in presentModel way. When I am in `ViewController` **E** I want to open another `ViewController` **F** in presentModel way. In that **F** `ViewController` I have a back button. When I click on that It should dismiss the **F** and show the **A** `ViewController`. But now when it dismissse shows **E**. How can I dismiss all other viewcontrollers except the **A** when I click the back button of **F**

Please help me. Thanks

**UPDATED**

```
-(IBAction)dismisthis:(id)sender{


UIViewController *dismissingViewController = self.presentingViewController;
while (dismissingViewController.presentingViewController != nil && [dismissingViewController isKindOfClass:[FrontViewController class]]) {
    dismissingViewController = self.presentingViewController;
}




[dismissingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about sending `Notification` using `NSNotificationCenter` from F and A will listen to it. Once A receives the notification, it will call `dismissViewController` which I think will dismiss all.

Comment: This is a poor solution.  Notifications should be used, as much as possible, to indicate an event occurred, not to trigger a specific action.

Comment: Agree that notifications should be used for events but in that case, notification is the fastest and easiest solution and relief the headache to access the the first view controller

Comment: "For every complex problem there is an answer that is clear, simple, and ... wrong." - H.L. Mencken  :-)

Comment: Agree too, but my solution is not wrong :) . At least if he changes anything in the flow, my solution still works. Yours may not work if one of the middle viewcontrollers was embedded in `UINavigationController`

Answer (score 3):

If you dismiss a view controller that is presenting another view controller, the entire hierarchy is dismissed.  It doesn't matter how many levels there are.  So all you have to do is find your view controller `A` and tell it to dismiss its presented view controller.

If `A` is always the bottom of the heap, you can use a simple loop to find it:

```
UIViewController *dismissingViewController = self.presentingViewController;
while (dismissingViewController.presentingViewController != nil) {
    dismissingViewController = self.presentingViewController;
}

[dismissingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                             completion:NULL];
```

Comment: This works, and I would recommend creating a subclass for your view controllers so you can ensure you are going back to the one you expect even if later on it is contained within another view controller.  To do this, you can simply change the while() above to check "dismissingViewController.presentingViewController != nil && [dismissingViewController isKindOfClass:[MyAViewController class]]".  Future iterations of the app may present "A" from another controller and without that check you may dismiss "A" by mistake.

Comment: But it says no visible interface for dismissViewController

Comment: this redirect me to the E not to A

Comment: Use the debugger to find out what `dismissingViewController` ends up being after the loop.

Comment: Your second condition is probably incorrect.  Possibly you want `[dismissingViewController isKindOfClass:[FrontViewController class]] == NO`

Answer (score 1):

At this moment i can think of three solutions

1. You should keep track of all viewControllers in a stackObject(which is an array) in Appdelegate. When you want it access this get these array and dismiss all view controler objetcs.
2. Each viewcontroller you can observer for a NSNotification which will listen for notification. When you need it in "F" just post the notification and this notification will dismiss the eviewcontrollers
3. Go for NavigationController so that you can push to rootviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIViewController *rootVC = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
[rootVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

// One-liner
// [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make A as rootViewController and use below code on Back button of "F":

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
```